# How can I add a jar at runtime when spark-submit is called

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Python wheel (.whl) that contains a jar that I have compiled myself that I want to use with pyspark. This shows the structure of the wheel:

```
$ unzip -l dist/foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Archive:  dist/foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     2187  05-09-2020 20:46   foo.py
166129636  05-04-2020 19:59   foo_jars/foo.jar
      874  05-09-2020 20:47   foo-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
       92  05-09-2020 20:47   foo-0.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
       33  05-09-2020 20:47   foo-0.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
      517  05-09-2020 20:47   foo-0.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
---------                     -------
166133339                     6 files
```

Note that the jar is in a subdirectory called `foo_jars`.

pip installing the package works fine. In `foo.py` I have code that  symlinks the .jar into `${SPARK_HOME}/jars` and a function `bar()` that uses code from the jar:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

module_name = Path(__file__).stem
package_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
jar_file_name = "foo.jar"
jar_file_path = os.path.join(package_dir, f"foo_jars/{jar_file_name}")
tgt = f"{os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME')}/jars/foo.jar"
os.symlink(jar_file_path, tgt)

def bar():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    # calls code in foo.jar
    spark._sc._jvm.com.packagename.classname.FunctionName()
```

I've got a script `test.py`:

```py
import foo

foo.bar()
```

which I submit using `spark-submit test.py`

When I do so it fails with

> TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Which I'm confident is because it cannot find the .jar

However if I immediately issue the same command `spark-submit test.py` ... this time it succeeds.

My assumption is:

- The jar gets successfully symlinked into `${SPARK_HOME}/jars` by the code in `foo.py` that executes at `import foo`
- The jar isn't available to the currently executing pyspark job (because its already been submitted)
- The jar *is* available on the second call to `spark-submit test.py` because it got symlinked on the previous call

So my question is...how can I add the jar at runtime (i.e. when `spark-submit` has been called) and use it? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the jar directly from the code without passing the same while doing `spark-submit` doesn't work because that path to jar is available only on master (hence executors will not be able to read it) and also not necessarily on the hdfs which the application might be using. Thus to make available such dependencies to your spark application you need to use `--jars` argument of the `spark-submit` command.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Comment: Thanks Mahendra, that confirmed my thinking and provided clarity around it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Anytime, let me know if that solves your case if not then I would be glad to share my code snippet.